# Constructor Parameter

Tags: c#

I am working through an example and came across the following:

```
public CustomerDetailsViewModel(
    IUIDataProvider dataProvider,
    string customerID,
    IToolManager toolManager = null)
    : base(toolManager)
{
    _dataProvider = dataProvider;
    Customer = _dataProvider.GetCustomer(customerID);
    Customer.PropertyChanged += Customer_PropertyChanged;
    DisplayName = Customer.CompanyName;
```

Can someone explain the following part in a bit more detail as I am not sure how it is used:

```
 IToolManager toolManager = null)
 : base(toolManager)
```

Comment: It's a default/optional parameter.

Comment: Followed by a chained call to the base class constructor (that's what the `: base(toolManager)` means).

Comment: It's passing `toolManager`, which is an optional parameter, through to the constructor of the base class of `CustomerDetailsViewModel`.

Comment: [Named and Optional parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd264739.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IToolManager toolManager = null)
```

This is what is called an [optional parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). When you call this method you do not have to provide it. If you do not, it is given the value specified in the method signature

```
 : base(toolManager)
```

This is a call to the constructor of the class that is extended by your class. I suggest you read up a bit on inheritance and constructor chaining.

Comment: That is what I initially thought, however the base class does not take type toolManager as a parameter

Comment: @user3532702 can you show the base class then? The `base` call is to the base constructor I can assure you of that.

Comment: I will double check everything again, I appreciate that what you are saying is correct I just can't see it at the moment

Comment: It was an oversight on my behalf